# Simple syntax issue with $_POST

Tags: php

I want to concatenate a variable within the $_POST[] brackets for a while loop. My question is, is it possible. Here is the code.

```
$m=0;

$_POST['tier_' . $m];
```

Comment: Have you tried it before you asked this question? You can easily test it yourself. If you tried, which problems did you encounter?

Comment: Yes I did try it. My mistake as there was something else wrong with the while loop when I worked in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. However your form should probably be more like:

```
<input type="text" name="tier[]" />
```

Then `$_POST['tier']` will be an array you can loop through.

Comment: @Dagon Erm, no, you'd access `$_POST[$m]` on the server side.

Comment: -weird look- You're not making any sense at all. Any more questions?

Comment: sorry i was going backwards on that one.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes, but the code sample you provided would cause a notice because it would try to check an index that does not yet exist. The following would work:

```
$m=0;

$_POST['tier_' . $m] = 'something';
```